# Asking for internship before or after the rejection?

Tags: hiring-process, internship, applications, germany, rejection

As far as I know, my application will be rejected for a junior developer position, what is the best time to ask for internship? Before applying for a junior position or after the rejection?

I'm from Asia and I don't have years of experience but I want to get a job in Germany while I have a short notice period full time job in my country.

Comment: Are you currently living in Asia and trying to get an internship in Germany?

Comment: @Toss Yes, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I live in The Netherlands, so it's different here. But across both our countries, we have a great need for developers at the moment. Being a developer myself, I know that a lot of companies are absolutely jumping at any chance of hiring the next/another/a new developer.

If you're hung up on that one company, by all means ask for an internship. Not quite sure if before or after would be better, I've never been in that situation.

However, as I said, the need for developers right now is immense. So I would advise you to just apply at another company for a similar/the same position.